# При обновлении с kali1 на kali2, поломался модуль requests

Tags: python, linux, python-2.x, requests

Ситуация в целом такая:

1. **Было** На kali 1:
   Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55)[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2. **Версия requests модуля 0.12.1**
2. **Стало** На кали 2:
   Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar 1 2015, 12:57:24) [GCC 4.9.2] on linux2. **Версия
   requests модуля 2.7.0**

Простой api_query для cryptsy поломался.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import time
import urllib

def api_query( method, req = {}):
        # API settings
        key = API_KEY # your API-key
        secret = API_SECRET # your Secret-key
        req['method'] = method
        req['nonce'] = int( time.time() )
        # generate the POST data string
        post_data = urllib.urlencode( req )
        sign = hmac.new( secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512)
        # generate the extra headers
        headers = { 'Sign': sign.hexdigest(), 'Key': key }
        url = 'https://api.cryptsy.com/api'
        print 'post_data = ' + post_data
        print 'headers = ' + str( headers )
        r = requests.post( url, data=post_data, headers = headers )
        print r
        for i in  r.__dict__:
                print ''
                print i, r.__dict__[i]
        return r.text
```

На kali 1 этот код работал и продолжает работать.
На kali 2 - всё поломалось.

```
>>> print api_query("getinfo")
{"success":"0","error":"Unable to Authorize Request - Check Your Post Data"}
```

Второй день гуглю, встретил такую штуку, на CentOS у кого то было, что при upgrade-е до 2.5.0 requests поломал headers-ы, типа они стали не case-sensitivity. Т.е. если на 0.12.1 headers чувствителен к регистру, и Sign для cryptsy отправляется верный, то на 2.7.0 может отправляется `headers.upper()`, или ещё какая-то бредятина.

И как дебажить это, научите кто-нибудь? Выставил nonce в одинаковое число, зарядил на kali1 и kali2 - post_data и headers, а так же `Sign` включительно - абсолютно идентичные. Т.е. не так работает сам метод `post` у нового модуля requests.

Wireshark-ом не могу посмотреть сессию, потому что там https. пробовал дампить response как словарь и по-элементно сравнивать, не видно там ничего такого. Да и разрыв 0.12.1 - 2.7.0 какой-то космический.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, requests работает так, что ему не нужна такая строчка

```
post_data = urllib.urlencode( req )
```

Но в данном случае её нужно оставить, для создания подписи.

А изменится всего одна строка кода:

```
r = requests.post( url, data = post_data, headers = headers )
```

На

```
r = requests.post( url, data = req, headers = headers )
```